# ng-click in Angularjs ui-grid cell Template doesn't work

Tags: angularjs-ng-click, ui-grid, celltemplate

I don't know why with the following template ng-click doesn't work:

```
<div>
<md-icon ng-click="console.log('hello'); $event.stopPropagation();" md-font-icon layout-fill ng-
         class="md-raised inline-icon fa statusCellIcon" style="z-index:1000;">
</md-icon>
```

$event.stopPropagation() executes but not the console.log.

someone knows why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution if someone is interested by was:

Expose the method to the ui-grid by adding the following to the grid options:

```
appScopeProvider: someFunction: function () { doSomeThing(); }
```

And in the ColumnTemplate of the grid add the following code:

```
<div>
<md-icon md-font-icon layout-fill class="inline-icon fa"
         ng-click="grid.appScope.someFunction(); $event.stopPropagation();"
         ng-style="{'cursor':'pointer'}">
</md-icon> ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
variable $scope.console = window.console;
```